# Collation issue with linked servers SQLServer and MySql and Incorrect String Value

Tags: mysql, sql-server

**Setup**
Have an SQL Server connecting to Mysql as a linked server.  Periodically a SQL Server Agent Job calls a stored procedure (SP) to check a flag in a SQL Server table, pass the contents (via a temp table) of unflagged rows to a SP in the mySQL db, flagging the original SQL Server records as they go.

**Problem**
Sometimes this all (appears to) works fine, other times, the mySQL db does not get the update data, even though the flag is set in the SQLServer.

Viewing the history of the server agent job I see an error like this

```
SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  Could not execute statement on remote server 'LINKED_MYSQL'.
 [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7215)  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKED_MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.21-log]Incorrect string value: '\xF8</val...' for column 'INFO' at row 1".
```

As there isn't a row INFO (anywhere) it looks like something systemy might be the cause.  I was wondering if the Collations might well be the problem.

SQL Server is:  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Whereas Mysql is: utf8.

I am unable to change the Collation of the SQL Server.

Any suggestions as to whether this is the likely cause or how to debug other solutions.  No other issues are to be found in the log files.

UPDATE:  So the error message says there is a problem with '\xF8</val'- 
there isn't any string in my data xF8 so something is being replaced here.

UPDATE 2: Yes this would tally with the content that sometimes gets transferred - there is a ø  (which is char \xF8) .

Updated Question:
How can I get SQL SERVER data into the MySQL Server without changing the collation on SQL SERVER?  I have already tried to change the collation for the MySQL DB and Table to "default collation: utf8mb4_general_ci   /   charset: utf8mb4

Fixing the collation in mySQL actually has solved the original problem - however one line of the mySQL SP

```
SET hostIP := (SELECT host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id());
```

Causes the  problem to reoccur.  Comment the above out hooray but leave it in booo.

Have tried

```
SET hostIP := (SELECT host COLLATE utf8_general_ci from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id());
```

but no cigar

Comment: Changing of collation can be done on a query-by-query basis.  You don't have to change it just at the server level.

Comment: Do you think that differences in Collation might cause such an error?

Comment: If you get an error, it should come up right away when you run the query.  Shouldn't have an impact on either system as long as you use a transaction.

Comment: ok so the \xf8 could well relate to the occurrance of the ø symbol which has recently appeared in the data

Comment: i was not seeing the errors originally as this was happening with a scheduled called to a MS SQL SP which in turn passes data to the MySQL SP.  I am now calling the MySQL SP (from SQL SERVER Mangement Studio) so can see the error in "real time"

Comment: Right - I sort of avoided the problem.  It turned out that the actual problem occurred when adding some data to the process (the ip address of the machines taken from the system) which was, I assume, in a different collation than the text I was sending across.  This was breaking the process.  Removing the addition of the ip address request in the sql allowed the process to proceed happily.  Was not able to get it working with though.